# Example of AudioStreamBasicDescription for 16hz, 16bit mono format as WAV file

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording

I'm having trouble with creating a description for the above format and have tried a number of things but keep getting an invalid param when trying to record.

Does anyone have an example of how to create to this format?

```
var audioFileOutputDescription : AudioStreamBasicDescription = AEAudioStreamBasicDescriptionNonInterleaved16BitStereo

    audioFileOutputDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
    audioFileOutputDescription.mSampleRate = 16000.0
    audioFileOutputDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 16
    audioFileOutputDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
    audioFileOutputDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1
    audioFileOutputDescription.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger |
        kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give the specific error you are getting and the line?  It's possible your error could be somewhere else other than the asbd.

Comment: Sure the error is:  OSStatus error -50 which translates to:  AVAudioSessionErrorCodeBadParam

Answer (score 1):

You declare AEAudioStreamBasicDescriptionNonInterleaved16BitStereo which is for 2 channels, then set mChannelsPerFrame = 1, which is for 1 channel.  That conflict in the number of channels might be the problem.

If that isn't the problem, one method to debug this is to start with a working asbd (from one of Apple's sample apps or guides), then change one thing at a time to find the unsupported parameter or parameter combination.

Also, WAV files are little endian.

Comment: That does not seem to work either.  And IIRC ARM devices are by default little endian so the kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian flag should be valid for wav files.

Comment: See additions to my answer.  Start with a more common 44.1 stereo asbd to find the unsupported parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see mBytesPerPacket or mBytesPerFrame set anywhere.

```
audioFileOutputDescription.mBytesPerFrame = 2;  // 1 mono channel * 2 bytes per channel
```

Comment: Even with adding that the format still isn't working correctly.  And Apple's documentation isn't very clear on what the parameters should be.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a converting audio unit as i find audio units don't support all the variations possible variations within an ASBD.

input -> converter AU -> do your magic AU -> convertback AU -> output

I think one of the biggest difficulties with audio units is ASBD's, each audio unit type supports only a number of formats, and as @hotpaw2 suggests, changing one parameter and testing is sometimes the only way to get to the bottom of the issue. I also find splitting audio units up into small individual audio units to do a single task works well as they become light weight and re-usable for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
fmt.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM; // 2
fmt.mSampleRate       = 8000.0;               // 3
fmt.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;                     // 4
fmt.mBitsPerChannel   = 16;                    // 5
fmt.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
fmt.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
fmt.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
fmt.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
// 7

fmt.mFormatFlags =                             // 9
kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian
| kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger
| kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
```